# How to configure Azure search to search Azure App service

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

In portal.azure.com, I have created an Azure Service App (Web app). The site is working great, it has folders and several htm files.

I want to have search functionality into this. Assuming Azure Search can do this, I created Azure Search service.

Now I don't know how to configure Azure Search to crawl Azure Service App.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Azure Search does not have an out of the box web crawler indexer.

Consider upvoting the [Support for crawling HTML/websites](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328653-support-for-crawling-html-websites) request to move it up the backlog.